# Extract code into dedicated function (Rust) (lifetime related)

Tags: rust

(copied from [my reddit question](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/yc19ly/help_trying_to_extract_code_into_its_own_function/)), hoping to get more answers)

I'm currently having a pretty hard time trying to make the following code work. I'm simply trying to extract a specific code block into it's own function, but I'm having a hard time due to the lifetimes related to it. I know very well there's a solution to this since it compiles with no problem when it is in it's own monolithic function, but the moment I try to start separating it, borrowck gets very angry.

```rust
trait Item<'s: 'i, 'i>: Sized + 'i {
    type Slice: 's;
    fn get<'a: 'i>(slice: &'a mut Self::Slice) -> Self where 's: 'a;
}

impl<'s: 'i, 'i> Item<'s, 'i> for &'i mut u32 {
    type Slice = &'s mut [u32];

    fn get<'a: 'i>(slice: &'a mut Self::Slice) -> Self where 's: 'a {
        &mut slice[0]
    }
}

// This don't work (even tried messing with HRTBs but still not able to make it compile properly)
/*
fn extracted<'a: 'i, 's: 'i, 'i, I: Item<'s, 'i>>(slice: &'a mut I::Slice) {
    for x in 0..4 {
        let func = I::get(slice);
    }
}
*/

fn main() {
    let mut array = [0, 0, 0, 0u32];
    let mut slice = array.as_mut_slice();

    let mutable = &mut slice;
    for x in 0..10 {
        let value = <&mut u32>::get(mutable);
    }
}
```

I tested out the suggestions from the Reddit answers, although it does not seems that the Copy trait has anything to do with it.

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=df7834b92effb4bd1e3bdb4d0bcc712f)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always make sure to include your code _in the question itself_ — not solely on an external site — so that the question makes sense by itself. ([More info.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). I've edited the question to take care of this for you.